# Equivalente ao sendFile no restify

Tags: node.js, restify

Gostaria de mostrar uma página ao chamar uma rota no node usando o restify

No express uso assim:

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})
```

Como seria no restify?

Se eu tento assim dá

```
TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o a API [**server-static-restify**](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#servestatic) para o envio de arquivos estáticos usando o método `restify.plugins.serveStatic()`.

Veja o exemplo:

```
const restify = require('restify');

const server = restify.createServer();

// exemplo GET para a url: 'localhost:8080/home/'
server.get('/home/*', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
  'directory': './front-end', // voce colocaria o valor do '__dirname'.
  'default': 'index.html' // arquivo html a ser enviado.
}));

const respond = (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.send({
    msg: "Mensgem via AJAX!"
  });
  return next();
}

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Servindo arquivo estaticos na porta: ' + 8080);
});
```

Neste exemplo, a rota e o diretorio especificado iram servir o arquivo localizado em `./front-end/home/index.html`.

Script no `index.html` para chamada AJAX:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
    const data = fetch("/api/home", {
      method: "POST"
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Tem como enviar parametros a partir deste codigo para a página?

Comment: Acredito que por se tratar de um envio de arquivo estatico, a unica maneira de esta pagina receber parametros e atraves de uma chamada AJAX, diferente do expressJS onde voce usa uma engine para renderizar a view em que voce passa um objeto para o metodo res.render() com os parametros desejados. Eu editei minha resposta e mostrei como fazer esta chamada AJAX.